# how to send a number from client to server

Tags: python

I can send messages in the form of strings but I cannot send integers to the server.
What I have done is this:

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

try:
    #create an AF_INET, STREAM socket (TCP)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();

print 'Socket Created'

host = 'localhost'
port = 6000

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

print 'Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

nb = input('Choose a number')
print ('Number%s \n' % (nb))

#Send some data to remote server
#message = nb

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.send(mySocket, nb, sizeof(int),0);
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print 'Send failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Message send successfully'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use int() and str() function for convert integer to string and send it

and in other side with int() function convert it to integer

look at these links

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str